# How can I run a shell as a user that has no shell access?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, centos7

Maybe I'm not using the right terms so allow me to explain myself using an example. Connecting over SSH as user "centos" and executing `cat /etc/passwd` in my Centos7 machine I get:

```
centos:x:1000:1000:Cloud User:/home/centos:/bin/bash
www:x:1001:1001::/home/www:/sbin/nologin
```

Now, if try `sudo su www -` I get: *This account is currently not available.*

That according to my limited knowledge is due to the *nologin* part. What I want to do is to be able to switch to the www user in the SSH session without (if possible) giving the www user the possibility to access directly the server over SSH, like when the root user tries to SSH and get an error telling that you are supposed to log in as *centos* and then change to root if needed.

What will be the steps to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/358740/147970

Comment: "shell access" kind of implies that user being able to log in directly.  Sure, you could block them from SSH specifically, but still allow password logins on a console terminal, serial port, or other place where you could run a getty daemon.  So that answers your question title, rather than what you're actually asking (about starting a shell as another user that can't login directly.)

Comment: I'll grant deman this, the title of the question is poorly worded compared to what the asker is actually trying to achieve per the text. Fixing.

Answer (score 36):

Just run a shell under the user.

```
sudo -u www bash
```

Answer (score 17):

The su command takes a shell [option](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html#OPTIONS) (`-s`), so you can specify which shell to use, allowing you to become the user.

```
sudo su www -s /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 3):

The command syntax you're looking for is `sudo -u www -s`

This will drop you into a shell as the `www` user even if they don't have a shell normally.

Answer (score -5):

Yes, you need to alter /etc/passwd - set a valid shell for this user.
In order to run commands as this user, sudo -u www might help.

Comment: That's 1) not what they asked and 2) even if it were this would be *terrible advice* to give to someone who's clearly unused to unix. Do **NOT** edit `passwd` manually if there is *any* alternative available.

Comment: It is the right answer for the title and diag. But detailed question is different. Why not drop question's rate?

Comment: It's terrible advice to access service accounts with a secure shell.

Comment: If you answered the title without reading the question then you deserve that -1 even more.

Comment: Would you kindly?

Comment: Additionally: it only answers how to add the shell. You could at least add how to prevent SSH access.